# Creating a function to replace NAs in the column that calculate the session

Tags: r, function, session

I have a data frame, which look like the sample dataframe below:

```
#sample data frame
   clientId actual_time           session
1  A        2016-11-01 00:00:00   1             
2  A        2016-11-01 00:05:00   1
3  A        2016-11-01 00:35:01   2
4  A        2016-11-01 00:40:00   NA
5  A        2016-11-01 01:10:01   NA         
6  B        2016-11-01 01:00:00   1
7  B        2016-11-01 01:05:00   1
8  B        2016-11-01 01:30:00   1
9  B        2016-11-01 01:40:00   1
10 B        2016-11-01 01:50:00   NA
11 C        2016-11-01 02:00:00   NA
12 C        2016-11-01 02:35:00   NA
13 C        2016-11-01 04:35:00   NA
```

I would like to fill the NAs in the column ’session’ with values with the logic defined as:

- For the same “clientId”, if the time difference between two subsequent row is >= 30 minutes, then the newer row will be in a new session (which equals the session of the older row plus 1); if the time difference between two subsequent row is < 30 minutes, then both row is in the same session with the same session number.
- The session number is a cumulative number starting from 1, i.e., for a new clientId, the session number starts from 1.

After the NA is filled up, the data frame will be like:

```
#sample data frame (result)
   clientId actual_time           session
1  A        2016-11-01 00:00:00   1             
2  A        2016-11-01 00:05:00   1
3  A        2016-11-01 00:35:01   2
4  A        2016-11-01 00:40:00   2
5  A        2016-11-01 01:10:00   3         
6  B        2016-11-01 01:00:00   1
7  B        2016-11-01 01:05:00   1
8  B        2016-11-01 01:30:00   1
9  B        2016-11-01 01:40:00   1
10 B        2016-11-01 01:50:00   1
11 C        2016-11-01 02:00:00   1
12 C        2016-11-01 02:35:00   2
13 C        2016-11-01 04:35:00   3
```

I have tried:

```
df<-data.frame(clientId=c(rep('A',5),rep('B',5),rep('C',3)),
       actual_time=as.POSIXct(c("2016-11-01 00:00:00","2016-11-01 00:05:00","2016-11-01 00:35:01","2016-11-01 00:40:00","2016-11-01 01:10:01",
                       "2016-11-01 01:00:00","2016-11-01 01:05:00","2016-11-01 01:30:00","2016-11-01 01:40:00","2016-11-01 01:50:00",
                       "2016-11-01 02:00:00","2016-11-01 02:35:00","2016-11-01 04:35:00")),
       session=c(1,1,2,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA))  

my_session<- function(df){

  for (i in 2:(dim(df)[1])){
    if(is.na(df$session[i])){
      if (df$clientId[i]==df$clientId[i-1]){
        if(as.numeric(difftime(df$actual_time[i], 
                               df$actual_time[i-1], Asia/Taipei,units =     "mins"))>30){
          df$session[i]<- df$session[i-1]+1
        }else{df$session[i]<- df$session[i-1]}
      }else{df$session[i]<- 1}
    }
  }

  return(df)
}

df2<-my_session(df)
```

The function did work. However, it is very slow since my actual dataframe is with 8 million rows(a 4G csv file).

I think the time is consumed when running the for loop. Is there a way to write a function that fill in the NAs without a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll propose a `data.table` approach which should scale a lot better than your existing function.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df) # or setDT(df)
DT[, session := cumsum(difftime(actual_time, shift(actual_time, 
               fill = min(actual_time)), units = "mins") > 30) +1L, 
    by = clientId]
```

What it does: it counts, by group of clientId, the cumulative number of times two `actual_time`s differ by more than 30 minutes. Of course you have to make sure the data is ordered by actual time.

The resulting table looks like this:

```
 #   clientId         actual_time session
 #1:        A 2016-11-01 00:00:00       1
 #2:        A 2016-11-01 00:05:00       1
 #3:        A 2016-11-01 00:35:01       2
 #4:        A 2016-11-01 00:40:00       2
 #5:        A 2016-11-01 01:10:01       3
 #6:        B 2016-11-01 01:00:00       1
 #7:        B 2016-11-01 01:05:00       1
 #8:        B 2016-11-01 01:30:00       1
 #9:        B 2016-11-01 01:40:00       1
#10:        B 2016-11-01 01:50:00       1
#11:        C 2016-11-01 02:00:00       1
#12:        C 2016-11-01 02:35:00       2
#13:        C 2016-11-01 04:35:00       3
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Even though it didn't deal with the NA problem and directly recalculate the column. It did work very fast. 
Anyway, I am going to use this solution to recalculate the session column when new data comes in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the ddply() to solve the problem.

```
df$actual_time <- as.POSIXct(df$actual_time)
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(clientId),transform, x2 = c(0,cumsum(diff(actual_time) > 30))+1 )

     clientId         actual_time session x2
1         A 2016-11-01 00:00:00       1  1
2         A 2016-11-01 00:05:00       1  1
3         A 2016-11-01 00:35:01       2  2
4         A 2016-11-01 00:40:00      NA  2
5         A 2016-11-01 01:10:01      NA  3
6         B 2016-11-01 01:00:00       1  1
7         B 2016-11-01 01:05:00       1  1
8         B 2016-11-01 01:30:00       1  1
9         B 2016-11-01 01:40:00       1  1
10        B 2016-11-01 01:50:00      NA  1
11        C 2016-11-01 02:00:00      NA  1
12        C 2016-11-01 02:35:00      NA  2
13        C 2016-11-01 04:35:00      NA  3
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use split function to break you dataframe to a list of dataframes that each dataframe corresponds to the same clientId and use lapply to iterate over the list:

```
dat.split <- split(x = sample.data, f = as.factor(sample.data$clientId))
replace.nas <- lapply(dat.split, function(df) { 
                        # Fix the na problem here 
                        # return fixed dataframe})

dat.final <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, replace.nas)
```

Comment: You should also try to find the row number of the NAs with using "is.na" and "which" functions: